# Why does a bash script continue running even though a dialog box is displayed on the screen waiting for an input from the user?

Tags: macos, bash, dialog, osascript

I have a bash script I'm using on Mac OS X (X.5 thru X.8) machines. In it is a dialog situation asking to continue the script by pressing "OK" or letting the script snooze by pressing "snooze". That part is working.

However, I was testing the script and wasn't able to press either button immediately and after a minute or two (i didn't time it), the script continued with the rest of process, letting the dialog stay on the screen.

I was under the impression that the script had to wait for user input?

Part of the script in question:

osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to activate'

return=`osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to display dialog "Text goes here. Please select OK or Snooze" buttons {"OK", "Snooze"} default button 1 with title "Text Here" with icon caution'`

```
    ############  BEGIN LOOP HERE  ##############
```

while [ "$return" == "button returned:Snooze" ]

```
        do
        Runs every 4 hours
        sleep 14400
        osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to activate'
        return=`osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to display dialog "Text goes here. Please select OK or Snooze" buttons {"OK", "Snooze"} default button 1 with title "Text Here" with icon 2'`
```

done

######  END LOOP HERE

```
    if [ "$return" == "button returned:OK" ]
        then
                    run the installer script here
            fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the whole right side of the return statement in back quotes, this will execute the osascript and set "return" to the string returned by that program:

```
return=`osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to display dialog "Text goes here. Please select OK or Snooze" buttons {"OK", "Snooze"} default button 1 with title "Text Here" with icon caution'`
```

Otherwise you're just setting return to the string on the right side of the '='.

Comment: I doublechecked and the back quotes are there. I've tried the following script and it, too, has the same issue. So, it must be a function of bash? When I ran the following script, the dialog box pops up and stays there. But the script continues and shuts down after the requisite 2 minutes, not waiting for the user to click "OK".
osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to display dialog "Text here" buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with title "title here" with icon stop'
  shutdown -r +2 >./test 2>&1 >./test2

Comment: More information: After about 2 min, the terminal displays this error "21:218: execution error: Finder got an error: AppleEvent timed out. (-1712)". Then the script continues.

Answer (score 0):

To ignore the timeout error you can try this.
We needed a script that prompts the user to change their password should there be 14 days or less until it expires. If they ignore the prompt the script will terminate due to the exit 0. You can edit this behaviour as you see fit but the point is that if **anything** else is returned apart from my condition test `"button returned:OK"` then the script will skip over the stuff I don't want it to run

```
if [ $daysRemaining -lt $daysBeforeExpire ]
    then
        echo "$userName has $daysRemaining day(s) remaining to change their password"
        echo "Informing User..."
        return=`osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to display dialog \"You have $daysRemaining day(s) to change your password... Logout and change password now?\" buttons {\"Later\",\"OK\"}"`
        if [[ "button returned:OK" = $return ]]
            then 
            echo "Returned OK"
            echo "Asking to log out."
            osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to log out"
        else
            echo "Returned Later - Skipping user log out"
            exit 0
        fi
    else
        echo "$daysRemaining day(s) remaining to change password"
fi
```

So in your case, this should work

```
    if [[ "button returned:OK" = $return ]]
        then
             run the installer script here
        else 
             sleep 100 #sleep the script OR
             exit 0    #end it
        fi
```